# How do I enforce absolute positioning and line height with CSS?

Tags: css, jquery, positioning

I've created a jQuery Sliding Drilldown plugin that works quite well, except for one part: the positioning of the arrows.  If I change the font size/line height of the element they're contained in, they move, which doesn't make sense to me. Can anyone tell me why?  Does line-height actually affect the location of 0,0 in an element? Or is something else going on that I'm missing?

And - This is the real question - can I do what I'm trying to do with **just CSS**?  I know I can use JavaScript to position them dynamically, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Here is the plugin on a very plain page:

http://thomporter.github.com/jquery-sliding-ajax-drilldown/demos/basic-plain.html

You can also check out the [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) I used to generate the CSS if you prefer, it's in the repo:

https://github.com/thomporter/jquery-sliding-ajax-drilldown/blob/master/src/lib/css/jquery.sliding-ajax-drilldown.scss

Comment: Not sure exactly, but might be because your using em to absolute position. em, at least for text anyway, cascades down through dom nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're problem here is that you set `font-size` on your `<a>` tags, that are all set to `display:block` and house the other elements you need.

When you increase the font size in `em` your `<a>` elements expand. As you're arrow images are also nested in your `<a>` elements and are absolutely positioned, if the container box changes size, the position of the arrows will change. This will occur regardless of the unit type you use for sizing, margin, padding etc.

Try to contain the text within it's own element. Seperate out your CSS into typography styles vs positioning styles, wrap the text for each line in a span element.

```
<li>
    <a href="#" data-id="BMW">
        <span>BMW</span>
        <span></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Then apply something like this with your seperated font styles applied to this span:

```
.ajaxdrilldown ul li a span:first-child {
    display:inline-block; /* IE7 will need a hack for this */
    position:relative;
    left:0.3em;
    font-size:1.4em;
    ...
}
```

This will allow the text to freely expand within the confines of its own element without affecting the layout of the other items.

You will also need to change this style on line 98:

```
.ajaxdrilldown div ul li a span
```

to something along these lines

```
.ajaxdrilldown div ul li a span:last-child
```

to stop the spans polluting each others distinct styles

On a side note, you don't need to set width:100% on an element that is display:block;. Remove the width declaration entirely as it's unnecessary and will likely cause trouble for others styling this.

Comment: This is by far the best answer I've received.  Unfortunately, it still leaves an issue.  Yes, I can have the fonts scale indepentently of the container, but in reality, the container should scale too, otherwise the font will scale out of the container.  After all of the feedback I've gotten here, and from doing more research I've decided JavaScript is the only way to reliably position the image.  If anyone feels differently, please let me know!

Comment: @thom my last comment about not setting widths unnecessarily on display:block items applies to that. Don't set a width, allow the div to expand freely based on its children, give it a min-width and max-width and voila no javascript needed

Answer (score 2):

Just did some testing and it is because your using em to absolute position. If you change it to px for example, and fix the padding-left which is also em based, the arrows stop moving when you change the font-size.

Comment: Very good answer.  Unfortunately, I wasn't completely clear with my problem.  I want the darned things to stay "in the middle" vertically as the font/line height are changed (not so much in a responsive way, more in a "someone downloaded the plugin and has re-configured the font size" way...)  I thought that by using ems I might get around this problem, but no, I haven't.  My choice is to either make them edit the top/left, or use JavaScript to position them I guess.  Unless anyone has any idea how to position these with CSS "correctly"?

Comment: for me it was: forgetting to add 'px'.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand, I created jsfiddle. Please have a look and let me this is what you are looking for or something else.

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/saorabhkr/Xbydb/

Updated the jsfiddle with line height. I would like to suggest put the same line height what ever the content height.
Please have a look at new jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/saorabhkr/Xbydb/2/

Comment: You're using pixels for everything, I'm trying to use ems as much as possible for scaling... I'm really starting to think I need to use JavaScript because in the end, the icon i need to position is pixels. =/

Comment: Doesn't matter you can use em instead of px. Its up to you.

Comment: If I use em, then the top position has to be adjusted when the line-height changes.  Setting the line-height or font-size of the positioned element isn't helping...  What I need is to be able to have the people using the plugin set their font size & line height on the text, and have the arrow show up vertically centered on the bar the text is on (without them having to adjust the top value.)

Answer (score 0):

For position absolute with CSS you must set this style for its

```
position:absolute;
left:0px;
z-index:10;
```

and you must set this style for its parent

```
position:relative;
```

best regards

Comment: I did that.  Did you even look at the source?  Or read the other answers?